# INST-6193 during Weblogic Admin Server config (11gR2)

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, soa, oim

Attempting to set up my OIM server's connection through configuring my WebLogic server.  Running ./config.sh from /home/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_IDM1/bin

```
javaINST-6193: The attribute JpsContextName in MBean com.oracle.sdp.messaging:Location=soa_server1,name=ServerConfig,type=SDPMessagingServerConfig,Application=usermessagingserver not found. Check the SOA version compatibility.
```

Checked out my usermessagingserver with my OEM page, doesn't seem to want to start, not entirely sure if this is the cause of this error.  Unable to upgrade to/find SOA 11.1.1.7

Running on centOS6
Weblogic version 1036
SOA version 11.1.1.6
OIM version 11.1.2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

you should upgrade your soa instance to 11.1.1.7 for 11gr2ps2 or 11.1.1.9 for 11gr2ps3